# Random New World in Conquest of Paradise save reverts back to standard North America

Tags: europa-universalis-iv, conquest-of-paradise

I tried searching for an answer but I didn't find anything.
With the new expansion, my friend and I are doing a playthrough as native Americans in a randomized new world, but last time we loaded up our save game, everything was reverted back to " standard North America ". I've tried the obvious things like reloading the game, and making sure the checkbox is marked, any help ?

Comment: my normal procedure is to right click on it on Steam, properties, verify local files (or something like that). It usually takes care of a lot of different issues

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue with the 1.4 version of the game and was fixed in [patch 1.5](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Patch_1.5).